# ¿como sulucionar este error de syntax?

Tags: php

al querer guardar los datos introducidos en mi formulario por medio de archivo .php, me avisa de que tengo un error de syntax el cual no eh podido detectar cual sea..................................................

```
<?php
        include_once('db.php')
        $matricula=$_POST['matricula'];
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
        $semestre=$_POST['semestre'];
        $paraescolar=$_POST['paraescolar'];
        $capacitacion=$_POST['capacitacion'];
        $propedeutica=$_POST['propedeutica'];
        $conducta=$_POST['conducta'];
        $asistencia=$_POST['asistencia'];
        $nombret=$_POST['nombret'];
        $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
        
        echo "Los datos son: <br>";
        echo "$matricula, $nombre, $apellidos, $semestre, $paraescolar, 
        $capacitacion, $propedeutica, $conducta, $asistencia,$nombret y $telefono";
        
        $conectar=conn();
        $sql="INSERT INTO alumnos (matricula, nombre, apellidos, semestre, paraescolar, capacitacion,
        propedeutica, conducta, asistencia, nombret, telefono)
        VALUES ($matricula, $nombre, $apellidos, $semestre, $paraescolar, $capacitacion,
        $propedeutica, $conducta, $asistencia, $nombret, $telefono)";
        $resul = mysql_query($conectar , $sql)or trigger_error("Query Failed SQL- Error: ".mysqli_error($conectar), E_USER_ERROR);
        
        
        echo "$sql";
       
        ?>
```

Comment: faltaría un `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el intérprete te dice que hay error de sintaxis, créeme, es que hay un error de sintaxis. Así que revisa bien tu código. ¿Sigues sin ver el fallo? No pasa nada, descansa un rato, distraete un poco... y luego vuelve al código, es muy posible que lo veas de golpe.

En este caso, es porque se te ha olvidado el `;` después del `include_once`:

```
include_once('db.php');
```

Un fallo bastante grande, no sólo por cometerlo, sino además por no saber verlo después de que te esté diciendo que hay un `sintax error`.

Comment: Gracias, no lo ah habia visto para nada

Comment: Si te ha servido, ¿qué tal puntuar arriba la respuesta y aceptarla como solución?